# associations between 3 classes

Tags: c++, associations

I have 2 classes A,B as below:

```
class A{
public:
   int size;
   A(int s){size=s;}
};

class B{
B(int d):A(d){}
};
```

I need to know how I can define another class, class C, so class B can update the size (or any values) in class A, but class C can access the updated value in class A.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `size` is public, so can be accessed from anywhere with access to an `A` object. `B` seems to be irrelevant and, as written, invalid. Is it supposed to derive from `A`? If so, why? What exactly do you want the relationship between the classes to be? What problems are you having accessing members of `A` when you want them?

Comment: @user13676: Was you problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood it correctly but it seems to me that you can inherit C from A, so that you can access its data as it is updated. Or you can create a data member of C of type class A, and implement getter in A and call from C whenever necessary. For example:

```
class C {
private:
    A a;
public:
    void foo() {
        a.getSize();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

simple, Write another class `class C` that inherits from `class B`. 
so, `class B` can access the `class A` data members as well. you can use public/protected or private inheritance. But `class B:class A` should only be public/protected.

Then Write set methods in `class B`(so class B can update the size) and get methods in `class C`(class C can access the updated value in class A).

You should create a pointer and type case accordingly.

OR

You can use singleton pattern to maintain a single object(instance). It depend on the your requirement.

Comment: I should have mentioned that class C and B are separate and cannot be inherited from each other (think client and server classes where the server is not trusted). However, A can be accessed by both and B can update it.

Comment: If, so just create an object of B or A and write a wrapper to get methods in A (or just call getter methods of A). As you have setter methods in B you can access from B as well.